# Are the init methods of a static final object called again and again when I use that object?

Tags: java, object, static, final, public

I have a library, in which I need only one configuration all through the app. 
I call a method in that library through a public static final reference in a Helper class to the library' s builder.

Schematically, it looks like this:

```
public class Helper{
       private static final Pattern a = ... ;
       private static final Pattern b = ... ;
       ....
       public static final Library.Renderer RENDERER = Library.getBuilder().
                        .add(a)      // setting the configuration 
                        .add(b)      // of the renderer
                        ...
                        .build();
}
```

And, I call the method in that library from other places like this

```
 String processedText = Helper.RENDERER.render(rawText);
```

Does it mean that each time I call the static RENDERER, it passes all the process of adding and building the method again and again?

**Note:** this is not about static variables. It is about the methods incorporated in the static object initialization. So, the question is whether the `static final RENDERER = ....` refers to the adding and building procedure, or to the final outcome of that adding and building procedure.

Comment: No, static initializers are called once: the time the class is invoked for the first time

Comment: @geo strictly speaking the time at which the class is loaded - and this can happen more than once if, for example, it's loaded into multiple classloaders.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I am not sure about that detail (I think the spec does *not* say *loading* implicitly). It could also be first usage ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is called only once.
Testing file :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int verify = Static.var;
    int verify2 = Static.var;
    System.out.println("verify:"+verify);
    System.out.println("Verify2:"+verify2);
}
```

And the Static class :

```
public class Static {

    public static int var = returnCount();

    public static int count = 0;
    public static int returnCount() {
        count = count + 1;
        return count;
   }
}
```

Result :

`verify:1
 Verify2:1`